# In Play 2.6, how to write a WS Client filter that forwards headers from a parent request?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

If I have a controller named `HomeController` that receives a request like `GET /foo` with a header `X-Foo: Bar`, I would like to create a WS client filter that will read the `RequestHeader` in the context and copy the header value to the outgoing WS request.

Example Controller:

```scala
import play.api.libs.ws.{StandaloneWSRequest, WSClient, WSRequest, WSRequestExecutor, WSRequestFilter}
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents,
                               myWsClient: MyWSClient)
                              (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index = Action.async {
    myWsClient.url("http://www.example.com")
      .get()
      .map(res => Ok(s"${res.status} ${res.statusText}"))(executionContext)
  }
}
```

The wrapper around WSClient that introduces the filter:

```scala
@Singleton
class MyWSClient @Inject()(delegate: WSClient, fooBarFilter: FooBarFilter) extends WSClient {
  override def underlying[T]: T = delegate.underlying.asInstanceOf[T]

  override def url(url: String): WSRequest = {
    delegate.url(url)
      .withRequestFilter(fooBarFilter)
  }

  override def close(): Unit = delegate.close()
}
```

And finally the WS filter itself:

```scala
@Singleton
class FooBarFilter extends WSRequestFilter {
  override def apply(executor: WSRequestExecutor): WSRequestExecutor = {
    (request: StandaloneWSRequest) => {
      request.addHttpHeaders(("X-Foo", "<...>")) // INSERT CORRECT VALUE HERE!
      executor.apply(request)
    }
  }
}
```

In the end, the expectation is that the request `GET http://www.example.com` contains the header `X-Foo: Bar`.

The special requirements that make this more interesting are:

- You can modify the `MyWsClient` class.
- You can modify the `FooBarFilter` class
- You can create HTTP controller filters (`play.api.mvc.(Essential)Filter`if it helps.
- You can create other classes/objects/etc
- You cannot modify the controller (because in our situation, we can't expect all existing controllers to be modified.
- The solution should work even if there's a a "service" layer between the controller and the WSClient invocation and doesn't involve passing down objects everywhere.
- The solution can alter other Play/Akka mechanisms, like the default Dispatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to put it into actual code and test if this works but here is an idea: it looks like since Play 2.1 [Http.Context is propagated even across async call](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights21#Http.Context-propagation-in-the-Java-API). And there is [Http.Context._requestHeader](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.1/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html#Z:Z_requestHeader--). So what you can try to do is to change `MyWSClient`  and `FooBarFilter` like this:

```
@Singleton
class MyWSClient @Inject()(delegate: WSClient) extends WSClient {
  override def underlying[T]: T = delegate.underlying.asInstanceOf[T]

  override def url(url: String): WSRequest = {
    val fooHeaderOption = Http.Context.current()._requestHeader().headers.get(FooHeaderFilter.fooHeaderName)
    val baseRequest = delegate.url(url)
    if (fooHeaderOption.isDefined)
      baseRequest.withRequestFilter(new FooHeaderFilter(fooHeaderOption.get))
    else
      baseRequest
  }

  override def close(): Unit = delegate.close()

  class FooHeaderFilter(headerValue: String) extends WSRequestFilter {

    import FooHeaderFilter._

    override def apply(executor: WSRequestExecutor): WSRequestExecutor = {
      (request: StandaloneWSRequest) => {
        request.addHttpHeaders((fooHeaderName, headerValue))
        executor.apply(request)
      }
    }
  }

  object FooHeaderFilter {
    val fooHeaderName = "X-Foo"
  }

}
```

The idea is simple: extract the header from the `Http.Context.current()` when `WSRequest` is created and attach it to the request using a `WSRequestFilter`

**Update: make it work in Scala API**

As it was pointed out in the comment, this approach doesn't work in Scala API because `Http.Context` is not initialized and is not passed between threads. To make it work a higher level magic is required. Namely you need:

1. Easy: A Filter that will init `Http.Context` for Scala-handled requests
2. Hard: Override `ExecutorServiceConfigurator` for [Akka's default dispatcher](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html) to create a custom `ExecutorService` that will pass `Http.Context` between thread switches.

The filter is trivial:

```
import play.mvc._
@Singleton
class HttpContextFilter @Inject()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends EssentialFilter {
  override def apply(next: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request => {
    Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context(new Http.RequestImpl(request), null))
    next(request)
  }
  }
}
```

And the add it to the `play.filters.enabled` in the application.conf

The hard part is something like this:

```
class HttpContextWrapperExecutorService(val delegateEc: ExecutorService) extends AbstractExecutorService {
  override def isTerminated = delegateEc.isTerminated

  override def awaitTermination(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit) = delegateEc.awaitTermination(timeout, unit)

  override def shutdownNow() = delegateEc.shutdownNow()

  override def shutdown() = delegateEc.shutdown()

  override def isShutdown = delegateEc.isShutdown

  override def execute(command: Runnable) = {
    val newContext = Http.Context.current.get()
    delegateEc.execute(() => {
      val oldContext = Http.Context.current.get() // might be null!
      Http.Context.current.set(newContext)
      try {
        command.run()
      }
      finally {
        Http.Context.current.set(oldContext)
      }
    })
  }
}


class HttpContextExecutorServiceConfigurator(config: Config, prerequisites: DispatcherPrerequisites) extends ExecutorServiceConfigurator(config, prerequisites) {
  val delegateProvider = new ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator(config.getConfig("fork-join-executor"), prerequisites)

  override def createExecutorServiceFactory(id: String, threadFactory: ThreadFactory): ExecutorServiceFactory = new ExecutorServiceFactory {
    val delegateFactory = delegateProvider.createExecutorServiceFactory(id, threadFactory)

    override def createExecutorService: ExecutorService = new HttpContextWrapperExecutorService(delegateFactory.createExecutorService)
  }
}
```

and register at using

```
akka.actor.default-dispatcher.executor = "so.HttpContextExecutorServiceConfigurator"
```

Don't forget to update the "`so`" with you real package. Also if you use more custom executors or `ExecutionContext`s, you should patch (wrap) them as well to pass `Http.Context` along the asynchronous calls.

Comment: This doesn't work (at least for the Scala API) since when the `Http.Context.current()` method is invoked, a `RuntimeException` is thrown with message: `"There is no HTTP Context available from here."`

Comment: @Alejandro, yes it looks like for Scala API you need a more hardcore magic (actually a copy of what Play does for Java API) to make it work. See my update.

Comment: `Http.Context` is deprecated since play 2.7. Anyway, it was a quite dirty hack for scala. It was always a java api.